# ASP.NET SQL Server login form

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to build a small login web application in ASP.NET but now I'm getting an error while filling and submitting the form in live browser preview

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());
    con.Open();

    string query = "select * from login where user_login='" + txtuser.Text+ "' and '" + txtpass.Text + "' ";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    string output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    if (output == "0")
    {
        Session["user"] = txtuser.Text;
        Response.Redirect("");
    }
    else
        Response.Write("Login Failed");
}
```

http://prntscr.com/gm0vrr

Comment: Do be careful of SQL injection as well, while this might be just a small demo and you are aware of it I just wanted to be sure. Read more about it here [W3Schools SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: Use quote to share the exception message instead of img.

Comment: You can't just load a bunch of columns into a single string. Perhaps in your SQL Query you need `select count(*) as c..` instead of `select * ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlDataAdapter daGetUserDetail = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from login where user_login='" + txtuser.Text + "'  and user_password='" + txtpass.Text + "'", con);

```
        DataTable dtGetUserDetail = new DataTable();
        dtGetUserDetail.Clear();
        daGetUserDetail.Fill(dtGetUserDetail);

        if (dtGetUserDetail.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Session["user"] = txtuser.Text;
            Response.Redirect("");
        }
        else
            Response.Write("Login Failed");
```

Comment: dear can you explain it which you have a problem in this code i will resolve your problem or  send me the file i will put your code and send

Answer (score 2):

You really should be using [parameter binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements) instead of injecting text into the query.

With that said, the error appears to be in the query's second AND clause as it is missing the column name:

```
and user_password = '" + txtpass.Text + "' ";
```

Additionally, consider not storing passwords in plain text as it could represent a security vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks but this sql query is right I tested that on sql query engine

Comment: Could you print that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use framework to do SQL Querying easily. I recommend you to learn about Entity Framework or Dapper. If you still want to use that way, please use the parameter like

```
SELECT * FROM UserLogin WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password
```

the @ is parameter and your code would be like

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlcon);
using (cmd)
{
     sqlcom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", TextBox1.Text));
     string output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

Or you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398383/the-secure-way-to-return-some-value-from-database-sql-server-asp-net). Someone has explained it for me before.